# How to relate the Arrays in Java?

Tags: java, arrays

I am writing a program on signal processing. An example of appearance of signals is below:

Two arrays: having corresponding elements. Always they have equal number of elements as:

```
String signal[] = {"x",  "y", "y"  "C", "C", "z","C","C","x","C"};
int time[] =      { 2,    5,   1,   4,   7,   8,  2,  6,  4,  3 };
```

In the, signal [], x, y, and z are the names of three signals. C tells their continuation.
in the times[] , integers shows the the time for which a signal appeared for current first time, under the C figure tells for which the signal continued for additional time. The math logic goes as:

```
the time of x =2,          (=2)
the time of y = 5          (=5)
the time of y = 1+4+7      (=12)
the time of z = 8 +2+6     (=16)
the time of x = 4+3        (=7)

I need the output as {x=2,  y=5,  y=12,  z=16,  x=7}
```

What should I do to relate the elements of the arrays to get this output?

Comment: Java has no magic trick to do this, you'll simply have to write it yourself. Possibly using a HashMap<String, Integer> or something like that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a very bad implementation, but if you have no other choice than formatting your input as you provided, this is the best I can do:

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    String signal[] = {"x",  "y", "y",  "C", "C", "z","C","C","x","C"};
    int time[] = { 2,    5,   1,   4,   7,   8,  2,  6,  4,  3 };
    int i=0;
    while (i < signal.length)
    {
        switch(signal[i])
        {

            case "x":
            {
                System.out.print("x = ");
                int sum = time[i];
                if(signal[i+1] == "C")
                {
                    i++;
                    while(i < signal.length && signal[i] == "C" )
                    {
                        sum += time[i];
                        i++;
                    }
                }
                else i++;
                System.out.print(sum + " ");

                break;
            }
            case "y":
            {
                System.out.print("y = ");
                int sum = time[i];
                if(signal[i+1] == "C")
                {
                    i++;
                    while(i < signal.length && signal[i] == "C" )
                    {
                        sum += time[i];
                        i++;
                    }
                }
                else i++;
                System.out.print(sum + " ");

                break;
            }
            case "z":
            {
                System.out.print("z = ");
                int sum = time[i];
                if(signal[i+1] == "C")
                {
                    i++;
                    while(i < signal.length && signal[i] == "C" )
                    {
                        sum += time[i];
                        i++;
                    }
                }
                else i++;
                System.out.print(sum + " ");

                break;
            }
        }
    }

}
```

Output: `x = 2 y = 5 y = 12 z = 16 x = 7`

Comment: Hi cagirici, Thanks for giving exactly what I needed. This is great for me.

Answer (score 4):

This is precisely the reason java has a class system. Why not create a signal class with necessary information for each signal rather than trying to keep a bunch of arrays in tune with each other. Or use a Map as suggested?

Answer (score 1):

```
package com.company;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        String signal[] = new String[]{"x", "y", "y", "C", "C", "z", "C", "C", "x", "C"};
        int time[] = new int[]{2, 5, 1, 4, 7, 8, 2, 6, 4, 3};

        int index = 0;
        while (index < time.length) {
            int sum = time[index];
            String sig = signal[index];
            while ((index < (signal.length - 1) && signal[index + 1].equals("C"))) {
                sum = sum + time[index + 1];
                index++;
            }
            System.out.println(sig + " " + sum);
            index++;
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Hi rogergl, Thanks a lot for this concise solution. My purpose is solved.